# Python print pdf file with win32print

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a pdf file from Python with module `win32print` but the only way I can print success is a text.

```
hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter("\\\\Server\Printer")
filename = "test.pdf"
try:
    hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ('PrintJobName', None, 'RAW'))
    try:
        win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, None, ".", 0)
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, "test")  # Instead of raw text is there a way to print PDF File ?
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
    finally:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
finally:
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
```

So instead of printing a text I need to print the "test.pdf" file.

I also tried with **`win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, None,  ".",  0)`** but it's not working, after some test like (getprinter, getdefault, setprinter, setdefaultprinter) it seems not to be attaching the printer. So at this way I can't get working.

This is the code I used !

```
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(hPrinter)
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, None,  ".",  0)
```

Answer (score 17):

> *I'd like a solution which is able to print about 100 pdf files daily
>   every about 200 pages long. Files are stored in certain directory.*

```
import win32api
import win32print
from glob import glob

# A List containing the system printers
all_printers = [printer[2] for printer in win32print.EnumPrinters(2)]
# Ask the user to select a printer
printer_num = int(input("Choose a printer:\n"+"\n".join([f"{n} {p}" for n, p in enumerate(all_printers)])+"\n"))
# set the default printer
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(all_printers[printer_num])
pdf_dir = "D:/path/to/pdf_dir/**/*"
for f in glob(pdf_dir, recursive=True):
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", f, None,  ".",  0)

input("press any key to exit")
```

---

Notes:

1. You can change the printer attributes, such as color/black, scaling, quality, etc, by using the [DevMode](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/PyDEVMODE.html) object (example on the GUI code).
2. Provide the absolute paths of the filenames
3. Give enough time to process the job before exiting the script.

---

While not direct answer to the question, I couldn't resist the opportunity to make a GUI using `tkinter`. It can be easily changed to select a dir - and all the files inside -  instead of a single file.

```
import win32api
import win32print
import traceback

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font # * doesn't import font or messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Python Printer")
root.geometry("410x310")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.tk.call('encoding', 'system', 'utf-8')

def font_size(fs):
    return font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=fs, weight='bold')

# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
#mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 10, padx = 0)

# Create a _printer variable
_printer = StringVar(root)
# Create a _color variable
_color = StringVar(root)
_filename = ""

# on change dropdown value
def sel_printer(*args):
    print( _printer.get() )
# link function to change dropdown
_printer.trace('w', sel_printer)

def sel_color(*args):
    print( _color.get() )
# link function to change dropdown
_color.trace('w', sel_color)

def UploadAction(event=None):
    global _filename
    _filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    #print('Selected:', _filename)

def PrintAction(event=None):

    PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} 
    pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(_printer.get(), PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
    properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2)
    properties['pDevMode'].Color = 1 if str(_color.get()) == "Color" else 2
    properties['pDevMode'].Copies = 1
    win32print.SetPrinter(pHandle, 2, properties, 0)

    if not _filename:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No File Selected")
        return
    elif not _printer.get():
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No Printer Selected")
        return

    try:
        #win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(_printer.get())
        win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", _filename, None,  ".",  0)
        win32print.ClosePrinter(pHandle)
    except:
        pass
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "There was an error printing the file :(")

choices = [printer[2] for printer in win32print.EnumPrinters(2)]
_printer.set(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()) # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, _printer, *choices)
popupMenu['font'] = font_size(12)
Label(mainframe, text="SELECT PRINTER").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)

# Dictionary with options
choices = ["COLOR", "MONOCHROME"]
_color.set("COLOR") # set the default option

popupMenu2 = OptionMenu(mainframe, _color, *choices)
popupMenu2['font'] = font_size(12)
Label(mainframe, text="COLOR MODE").grid(row = 3, column = 1)
popupMenu2.grid(row = 4, column =1)

Label(mainframe, text="SELECT FILE").grid(row = 5, column = 1)
button = Button(mainframe, text=u"\uD83D\uDCC1" ' BROWSE', command=UploadAction)
button['font'] = font_size(12)
button.grid(row = 6, column =1)


_copies = IntVar()
_copies.set(1)

def copies_increase(event=None):
    _copies.set(_copies.get() + 1)

def copies_decrease(event=None):
    _copies.set(_copies.get() - 1)
    if _copies.get() < 1 :
        _copies.set(1)

Label(mainframe, textvariable=_copies).grid(columnspan=2)
button_frame = Frame(mainframe)
button_frame.grid(columnspan=2)


dec_button = Button(button_frame, text=u"\u2212", command=copies_decrease, fg="dark green", bg = "white", height=1, width=3 )
dec_button['font'] = font_size(10)

inc_button = Button(button_frame, text=u"\uFF0B", command=copies_increase, fg="dark green", bg = "white", height=1, width=3 )
inc_button['font'] = font_size(10)

button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

dec_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)
inc_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)

Label(mainframe).grid(row = 10, column = 1)
p_button = Button(mainframe, text=u'\uD83D\uDDB6' + " PRINT", command=PrintAction, fg="dark green", bg = "white")
p_button['font'] = font_size(18)
p_button.grid(row = 11, column =1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/x011/a6fc62c42ec8adb1d648e3a1827134bf)

[image]
[image]

---

Sources:

1. [Python printing a pdf file on my Brother Laser printer (Duplex print on/off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118645/python-printing-a-pdf-file-on-my-brother-laser-printer-duplex-print-on-off)
2. [Python print pdf file with win32print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249360/python-print-pdf-file-with-win32print)
3. http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/PyDEVMODE.html
4. https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/printing-using-python.502484/
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37586129/797495
6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638762/797495
7. https://t.codebug.vip/questions-712908.htm
8. [How do I create a button in Python Tkinter to increase integer variable by 1 and display that variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598010/how-do-i-create-a-button-in-python-tkinter-to-increase-integer-variable-by-1-and)
9. https://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/ (**this may also be a solution**)

---

PS: I may not win the bounty, but I certainly enjoyed making the GUI. `tkinter` layout was the hardest part!

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. I had problem with Shellexecute to print pdf. So I used rather [this](https://superuser.com/a/1529950/71797) for printing. I've mistaked that I said that gscript is obsolete. gsprint.exe has problems but gswin64.exe is OK.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found a solution. Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: I love the look of this and it is exactly what I want to add to my script.  My only problem is that I keep getting "pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenPrinter', 'Access is denied.')" in PrintAction on the pHandle.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @NMALM Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37586129/797495

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm afraid I don't see the answer there.  I can't tell what they're doing differently than the script here.  ```PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} 
    pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(_printer.get(), PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
    ``` I don't see how this is any different.

Comment: `PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER} ` VS `PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} `, try changing this.

Comment: @PedroLobito Your Tkinter GUI had a little error in https://gist.github.com/OttomanZ/9e33fde4e00f3189eaa0ac0e5a0734cf . I have fixed it please update the source code there because editing queue is full. You need to import `askopenfilename()` instead of `filedialog.askopenfilename()` because of importing structure.

Comment: @MuneebAhmadKhurram I've just tested the code on python 3.6.8 and it works as expected. We start by importing `askopenfilename` like this: `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename`  and calling  `filedialog.askopenfilename()` as you proposed is redundant.  You're the 1st user to report a "_editing queue is full_" error. The error is probably related to your python version or printer setup, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I have used and it works correctly.

```
name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter() # verify that it matches with the name of your printer
printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} # Doesn't work with PRINTER_ACCESS_USE
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name, printdefaults)
level = 2
attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)
#attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 1  #no flip
#attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 2  #flip up
attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = 3   #flip over
win32print.SetPrinter(handle, level, attributes, 0)
win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)['pDevMode'].Duplex
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print','manual1.pdf','.','/manualstoprint',0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter("\\\\Server\Printer")
```

This method accepts a String, not the printer object you tried to pass it.

Comment: Hello @WJVDP, in this case it returns 42 but nothing printed.